# How to implement criteria "Point A and Point B must have at least a difference of 2" in while-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am running into a problem regarding my rock-paper-scissors game. To end the game it must have both the criteria:

- One player must reach at least 5 points
- Difference of the two players' score must be at least two

I have made the part where one of the scores must be at least 5. Also, tried putting the difference condition in the While-loop line but to no avail. Doing this makes the game end if either one player reaches 5 or one player has reached a difference of more than two. The criteria says that BOTH needs to be satisfied, not just one or the other. The rock paper scissors coding was already given by the authority.

```
import play_rock_paper_scissors as play_rps

NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN = 5

num_rounds_played = 0
points_a = 0 
points_b = 0 

while (points_a < NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN and points_b < NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN) or \
abs(points_a - points_b)<2:


    winner = play_rps.play()
    print('Outcome of round', num_rounds_played,':',winner)
    num_rounds_played += 1
    if winner == 'a':
        points_a += 1
    elif winner == 'b':
        points_b += 1


print('Number of rounds played =',num_rounds_played) 

print('A has won',points_a,'rounds')
print('B has won',points_b,'rounds')
```

I expected the outputs to be something like:

```
[1] A: 2 B: 5
[2] A: 5 B: 3
[3] A: 0 B: 5
```

But actual output is:

```
[1] A: 6 B: 8
[2] A: 2 B: 4
[3] A: 9 B: 11
```

which does not satisfy the 'cannot exceed 5' criteria.

Comment: If it needs to satisfy __BOTH__ criteria at the same time, then if players win in turns it can get arbitrarly large. Only after one of the players wins twice in a row (provided there was a tie before) or thrice (provided the player was one point behind) will the game end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally instead of a long condition which people are going to be confused about, you can write a properly named function:

```
def should_end(points_a, points_b):
  # first condition - one player crossing the threshold
  if points_a < NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN and points_b < NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN:
    return False
  # second condition - points difference at least 2
  if abs(points_a - points_b)<2:
    return False

  # both a satisfied
  return True

while not should_end(points_a, points_b):
```

If you can't use a function for this assignment, you can still rewrite the condition to be more readable / closer to what you want to say. You've got 2 ending conditions, so

> don't continue if
>     either player reached NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN
>     and
>     point difference is >= 2

which makes

```
while not ((points_a >= NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN or points_b >= NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN) and abs(points_a - points_b)>=2)
```

You can transform it from there if you don't like the leading `not`.

Comment: I'd like to use a def() function as well but the task restricts me to using a While function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both criteria to be fulfilled, you should use the `and` logical operator instead of the `or` operator:

```
while (points_a < NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN and points_b < NUM_POINTS_TO_WIN) and abs(points_a - points_b) < 2:
# Here ---------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Yes, I changed it to "and" but that still results in outputs such as [A] = 1, [B] = 4. This is incorrect due to none of the players reaching 5. I have fiddled with changing the "and" to "or" vice versa and I've got nothing right.